# add additional non pairs on top of pairs of data

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file as such:

```
_LOG_START_1_,,,,,,,,,
.,,,,,,,,,
C1,D1,,,,,,,,
TPROG_LAYER ,,,,,,,,,
Layer_00 , 3.59ms,Layer_01 , 3.50ms,Layer_02 , 3.65ms,Layer_03 , 3.69ms,Layer_04 , 3.65ms
Layer_05 , 3.64ms,Layer_06 , 3.63ms,Layer_07 , 3.66ms,Layer_08 , 3.68ms,Layer_09 , 3.68ms
.,,,,,,,,,
C2,D2,,,,,,,,
TPROG_LAYER ,,,,,,,,,
Layer_00 , 3.58ms,Layer_01 , 3.49ms,Layer_02 , 3.63ms,Layer_03 , 3.66ms,Layer_04 , 3.61ms
Layer_05 , 3.66ms,Layer_06 , 3.63ms,Layer_07 , 3.63ms,Layer_08 , 3.66ms,Layer_09 , 3.64ms
_LOG_END_1_,,,,,,,,,
```

I used the code:

```
pairs_ = dict()
with open('text.txt', 'r') as file:
    for i, j in re.findall(r'(Layer_\d+)\s,\s(\d+\.\d+)ms', file.read()):
        pairs_.setdefault(i, []).extend([i, j])

pd.DataFrame(pairs_.values())
```

to put the pairs in parallel, it gave me:

[image]

however I want to keep the C1, D1, C2, D2 as such, (not at header):

[image]

Anyone one know how I can deal with it? much appreciation

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new dataframe with just `C1`, `D1`, `C2` and `D2` as values and concatenate the two

```
pairs_ = dict()
with open('text.txt', 'r') as file:
    for i, j in re.findall(r'(Layer_\d+)\s,\s(\d+\.\d+)ms', file.read()):
        pairs_.setdefault(i, []).extend([i, j])

df = pd.DataFrame(pairs_.values())
df2 = pd.DataFrame({0:['C1'], 1:['D1'], 2:['C2'], 3:['D2']})
df = pd.concat([df2, df], axis=0)
df
```

Answer (score 0):

Store the headers as a temporary array and use them as your `pairs_.keys()`

```
pairs_ = dict()
current_head = None
with open('text.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        head = re.findall(r'(C\d+),(D\d+)', line)
        if len(head) > 0:
            current_head = head[0]
            pairs_[current_head[0]] = []
            pairs_[current_head[1]] = []
            continue
        values = re.findall(r'(Layer_\d+)\s,\s(\d+\.\d+)ms', line)
        for i, j in values:
            pairs_[current_head[0]].append(i)
            pairs_[current_head[1]].append(j)
            
pd.DataFrame(pairs_)
```